# Emulating fluent interfaces in bash

Tags: bash, fluent-interface

In bash, is there some way (which may even resort to using `eval`) to emulate a fluent interface, something like

```
expect 3 to_be 4
```

where `expect` and `to_be` are functions?

Or is there at least some way to nest function calls, something like

```
expect to_be 3 4
```

so that to_be is a function that receives 2 parameters, and expect is a function which evaluates the result of the to_be function?

Answer (score 2):

As to the second question,

```
expect "$(to_be 3 4)"
```

should work.

Comment: +1 Wow, didn't know this actually works... much better aproach than using eval :-).

Answer (score 1):

this can do everything, more than what you want so maybe add argument checks

```
expect() { eval "$@"; }
```